# Replace regex pattern to lowercase in java

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

I'm trying to replace a url string to lowercase but wanted to keep the certain pattern string as it is.

eg: for input like:

```
http://BLABLABLA?qUERY=sth&macro1=${MACRO_STR1}&macro2=${macro_str2}
```

The expected output would be lowercased url but the multiple macros are original:

```
http://blablabla?query=sth&macro1=${MACRO_STR1}&macro2=${macro_str2}
```

I was trying to capture the strings using regex but didn't figure out a proper way to do the replacement. Also it seemed using replaceAll() doesn't do the job. Any hint please?

Comment: Which parts exactly should change and how should they change? Based on your title you want to replace with uppercase version, but your examples do something opposite.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. My point is to twist the upper/lower case of all strings excluding the certain patterned strings, so I wanted to do something like replaceAll("(.*)?\\$\\{\\w+\\}")) and lowercase the (.*) part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to change any uppercase character which is not inside `${...}` to its lowercase form.

With construct

```
Matcher matcher = ...

StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
while (matcher.find()){
    String matchedPart = ...
    ...
    matcher.appendReplacement(buffer, replacement); 
}
matcher.appendTail(buffer);
String result = buffer.toString();
```

or since Java 9 we can use [`Matcher#replaceAll​(Function<MatchResult,String> replacer)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.util.function.Function)) and rewrite it like

```
String replaced = matcher.replaceAll(m -> {
    String matchedPart = m.group();
    ...
    return replacement;
});
```

you can dynamically build `replacement` based on `matchedPart`.

So you can let your regex first try to match `${...}` and later (when `${..}` will not be matched because regex cursor will not be placed before it) let it match `[A-Z]`. While iterating over matches you can decide based on match result (like its length or if it starts with `$`) if you want to use use as replacement its lowercase form or original form.

BTW regex engine allows us to place in `replacement` part `$x` (where `x` is group id) or `${name}` (where `name` is named group) so we could reuse those parts of match. But if we want to place `${..}` as literal in replacement we need to escape `\$`. To not do it manually we can use [`Matcher.quoteReplacement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement(java.lang.String)).

Demo:

```
String yourUrlString = "http://BLABLABLA?qUERY=sth&macro1=${MACRO_STR1}&macro2=${macro_str2}";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{[^}]+\\}|[A-Z]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(yourUrlString);

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while(m.find()){
    String match = m.group();
    if (match.length() == 1){
        m.appendReplacement(sb, match.toLowerCase());
    } else {
        m.appendReplacement(sb, Matcher.quoteReplacement(match));
    }
}
m.appendTail(sb);
String replaced = sb.toString();
System.out.println(replaced);
```

or in Java 9

```
String replaced = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{[^}]+\\}|[A-Z]")
        .matcher(yourUrlString)
        .replaceAll(m -> {
            String match = m.group();
            if (match.length() == 1)
                return match.toLowerCase();
            else
                return Matcher.quoteReplacement(match); 
        });
System.out.println(replaced);
```

Output: `http://blablabla?query=sth&macro1=${MACRO_STR1}&macro2=${macro_str2}`

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I need! I'm with Java 8 so will use the old school way. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

This regex will match all the characters before the first `&macro`, and put everything between `http://` and the first `&macro` in its own group so you can modify it.

```
http://(.*?)&macro
```

[Tested here](https://regexr.com/3tvrp)

UPDATE: If you don't want to use groups, this regex will match only the characters between `http://` and the first `&macro`

```
(?<=http://)(.*?)(?=&macro)
```

[Tested here](https://regexr.com/3tvs5)

Comment: but this works for only one group of the "macro" right? what if there're multiple of this macro group? and it's the "${macrovalue}" part it needs to keep as it is.

Comment: It doesn't matter how many macros you have. It will stop matching once it reaches the first one.